# Try np.where() but "could not convert string to float" error

Tags: python, numpy

I searched for topics with the same error, but I found nothing that truly resembles my case.

```
char_list = ',~:;=≠!*#%$@'

def replace_char(matrix, char_list):
  len_matrix = matrix.shape[0]
  new_matrix = matrix.copy()
  for i in range(len_matrix):
    char = char_list[i * len(char_list) // len_matrix]
    new_matrix[i] = np.where(new_matrix[i] == 1.0, char, " ")
  return new_matrix
```

I have a "3D numpy matrix" full of 1 or 0. I want to replace 1 by "char" depending on the depth of the layer. After that I crunch with this function

```
def crunch(matrix):
  matrix_2D = matrix[0]
  for i in range(matrix.shape[0]):
    matrix_2D = np.where(matrix[i] != " ", matrix[i], matrix_2D)
  return matrix_2D
```

This function works fine, but the first one gives me this error.

```
new_matrix[i] = np.where(new_matrix[i] == 1.0, char, " ")
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

If I change "char" and "espace" char to "float" or "int" it works well. So I looked for a way to convert "float matrix" to "string matrix" but nothing works as I want.
You can see that my final goal is to general item in 3D matrix with 1 and then print them in ASCII by replacing char by their depth and finally crunch layer to print it.

Thank you for your consideration

Comment: Numpy arrays cannot contain python strings. A simple solution is to change `char_list` to integer data using the `ord` function. `char_list_int = [ord(ch) for ch in char_list]`. Then, when you are ready to print the result, you can convert back to string data. For example `int_array_to_string=lambda arr:''.join([chr(item) for item in arr])`.

Comment: What is `matrix`? `dtype`? You can't put a string into an array of floats.

Answer (score 0):

You need to test the steps in the problem line

```
new_matrix[i] = np.where(new_matrix[i] == 1.0, char, " ")
```

First does the condition work:

```
new_matrix[i] == 1.0
```

Then the `where` - remember this is a function.  All the arguments to a function are evaluated before being passed in.

```
np.where(new_matrix[i] == 1.0, char, " ")
```

Finally, does the assignment work? What is the result - no guessing, verify.  Check the dtype.

```
new_matrix[i] = ...
```

The `where`, given `char` and " " arguments, will return a string dtype array.  If `new_matrix` is float dtype, this will produce your error.

```
In [76]: m = np.zeros(3)
In [80]: np.where(0,"#"," ")
Out[80]: array(' ', dtype='<U1')
In [81]: m[1] = np.where(0,"#"," ")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [81] in <cell line: 1>
    m[1] = np.where(0,"#"," ")
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```